# I want to make multi tenant site in identity 2.0 but not using user table. Can anyone give any demo project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, identity, multi-tenant

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    Startup.DataProtectionProvider = app.GetDataProtectionProvider();
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationCustomManager>(ApplicationCustomManager.Create);
}
```

I Need custom manager code for identity 2.0 in asp.net mvc.

Here i need tenant not for user but i have a table named site. I want site CURD handle by owin context.

I need any example of custom application manager code for any other entity except user and role.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this gets you started

```
 public class ApplicationCustomManager : IDisposable
{
    public ApplicationCustomManager(ApplicationDbContext _applicationDbContext)
    {
        //do any operations as per your requirements with _applicationDbContext


    }
    public static ApplicationCustomManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationCustomManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        var _applicationCustomManager = new ApplicationCustomManager(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>());
        return  _applicationCustomManager;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {



    }
```